# Nginx timing out for sse

Tags: django, nginx, server-sent-events

My stack is gunicorn, gevent worker, nginx & django. I've been able to get [SSE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) working after quite a bit of struggle (no, I do not want to use node.js, socket.io, tornado, twisted or the nginx push module or other tools - would like to use the above listed stack). I will eventually use a redis backed queue for pubsub, but not right now while I am debugging.

In my dummy/test program, I am able to send updates to the browser/client (using browser for testing) through SSE, and my task takes 2 seconds to complete (I just put a sleep there). Works as expected.

When I increase the sleep to over 60 seconds (i.e. I send an update back to the client less frequently), I get a timeout on my browser. How do I tell nginx not to timeout for `event-stream` content that will a long time (> 5 minutes perhaps)?

My nginx.conf:

```
upstream app_server {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
 listen 80 default;
 client_max_body_size 4G;
 keepalive_timeout 5;
 root /home/ubuntu/webapps/testt;
 error_log    /var/log/nginx/sse.error.log debug;

 location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header Connection '';
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_cache off;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   chunked_transfer_encoding off;
   proxy_redirect off;
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
     proxy_pass http://app_server;
     break;
   }
 }
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
 location = /500.html {
   root /path/to/app/current/public;
 }
```

}

My client that is expecting messages back from the server:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source = new EventSource('/events1/');
        var events_dom = $("#events");

        source.onmessage = function(message) {
                        $('#events').append('<li>'+message.data+'</li>');
                    }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I map a url to sse_request():

```
def event_stream()
    while True:
        time.sleep(70)
        yield 'data: %s\n\n' % unicode(datetime.datetime.now())

def sse_request(request):
    return HttpResponse(
            event_stream(),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Comment: Did you try `proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade'`?

Comment: did u manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You (most likely) don't want to disable this behavior in nginx. Instead you should make your code compatible with what nginx does.

### Why You Want This

Imagine nginx would let just any SSE open even when there are not data being send over it at all. That means that anyone could just open SSE on your server and forgot about it and your server would not learn about that connection being wasteful for a long time (depending on how often you transmit some data over it) while keeping it open. Every connection on server is a resource so there is finite number of connections you could handle at any given time. Therefore this would make it very easy for single attacker with very little resources to exhaust all of your connection leading to Denial of Service. This type of vulnerability would fall under [Slow DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_DoS_Attack) category.

### How To Solve The Problem

Instead of configuring nginx to stop doing this you should change your code to do periodic aliveness checks on the SSE. The simplest way to do is is to start a thread or async action that would every n seconds (say every 10s) send dummy message to the client "Hey I'm still here wanting to talk to you are you listening to me?". This is usually called ping or [heartbeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_%28computing%29) message.

I don't know django myself but check for [this for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766687/python-how-to-send-heartbeat-using-websocket-client) since the solution you need is very similar to the one given there.